# In app purchase iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an application. I want to add in-app purchases.

I want to put one chapter purchasable. It's already in the application, just unlock it through plist.

So when the user do purchase I don't want to download anything. I just want to change the value in plist.

So is it possible? Without downloading a new build. Can I unlock that chapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? Many people unlock things without downloading. Just keep a flag in your plist and update it after purchase. In your code, before showing the chapter check the flag to test whether it is unlocked or not. 

One things is you can not edit file that is in the resource directory. You need to save your file in document directory. If that is your problem, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155952/iphone-writetofile-not-saving-new-entry-into-plist/) previous question might help you.

Comment: Apple encourages you to choose between “Content,” “Functionality,” “Services,” and “Subscriptions” when considering the possible categories for your in-app offerings. then what type i have to select.
i just want to update the flag.

Comment: I mean to update the flag locally. When you get confirmed in the client that purchase is completed, then u can update the local flag in the client. Sorry, I'm not sure about the categories.