# reading image from document folder

Tags: iphone, png

if i place a image.png file in my resource, iphone will be able to read it. if i place a image.png file in iphone document folder it doesn't read?

i am sending the image over from my server, into the document folder. no problem with that.

i thought iphone will auto find the image file either in resource folder or document folder?

i did write any code for my app to locate the folder of my image, just called it by its file name, which is correct.

any ideas?

thks

```
// Get path to doc folder
NSArray *docpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [docpaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];      
self.data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:docpath];
```

done loading the plist from doc folder.

now i go to plist, get the file name and display for cell.

```
NSDictionary *dataItem = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:[dataItem objectForKey:@"Icon"]];
```

how can i specifiy the image is in my document folder?

Comment: If you're trying to have iPhone auto-find the image for use as a home-page/bookmark icon, place the image in the document root with the name `apple-touch-icon.png` or `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`. If it's an image for use in the web-page itself please show your code.

Comment: i am using the image as icon, for table cell. loading from resources folder is fine. strangely, 1 manage to update the image 1 time than thats it. i delete all the images in document folder, sent again, it doesn't works. to add, my image filename are place in a plist as string. the plist is sent from server together with image. i checked, all files correctly received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an UIImage from a file by using [imageWithContentsOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile:). However you can not read the file just specifying the name if it is in document folder. You need to get the path of your file. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155952/iphone-writetofile-not-saving-new-entry-into-plist/3156393#3156393) to get an idea of how to get the file path of document folder.

-- edit
If your plist contains the file names in document folder, then append the filenames from plist to document folder path to get the full path. Hope it helps.

```
NSArray *docpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [docpaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *dataItem = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dataItem objectForKey:@"Icon"]];
cell.icon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: hm.. i can't write the exact file name inside my code as it changes. any suggestion?

Comment: when you are writing the file in document folder after getting it from server, u obviously know the name. right? u need to save the name somewhere (may be in a variable) and then use it.

Comment: hey i just got it too! thks ya!!